# Symfony 2.3.3 Embedding Controller

Tags: php, twig, symfony-2.3

Im trying to embed a controller inside a twig template.  Its documented here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html and have read various questions on stackoverflow about it like this one: [How to insert a Controller in Twig with "render" in Symfony 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221230/how-to-insert-a-controller-in-twig-with-render-in-symfony-2-2)

However, when I try to embed my controller i get an error: "**The function 'controller' does not exist**"

My twig template looks like this:

```
<div class="section">
    <div id="a" class="section_column">
        {{ render(controller('MySymfonyBundle:AccessPage:load', {'page_id':'1'})) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller that is being embedded does some db selects etc then renders another view to include inside this template.

This is the full error:

```
array(
['message'] =>
'Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: "The function "controller" does not exist in "<div id="{{ identifier }}" class="section">
<div id="a" class="section_column">
{{ render(controller('ABCBundle:Site:grabPage', {'page_id':'1'})) }}
</div>
</div>" at line 3" at /www/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php line 555'
['context'] =>
array(

['exception'] =>
array(

)
)
)
```

this just doesnt seem to work =(  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are sure to have the correct version of TwigBridge? https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.3.3/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/HttpKernelExtension.php#L41

Comment: And the right version of SF?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Twig Bridge is definitely installed even though I cant see a version number in the file however my version is 89 lines the same as the one you linked to.  I havnt got a 'use' statement at the top of my controller thought which makes me think I need to include the class namespace in my controller. symfony is version 2.3.3 installed via composer and everything else works a treat.

Comment: Did you start with Symfony Framework Standard edition or did you "manually" make your project using Symfony Framework? You could try downgrading to 2.3.2 (using composer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this was erroring is because I was using the twig string loader and not loading a twig file.  rendering controllers inside twig content must not work from a string.

The twig template was stored in a mysql database and being extracted with Propel 1.6 then passed to the twig string loader to render the html.