# Create a form in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have an simple HTML upload form in the image.html.twig file  which is included by the base.html.twig and all the views extends this base.html.twig layout. I dont want to use the HTML way of creating the form. I have previously created form using the form builder but not in this way. How do I create a form using the form builder for this kind of problem? Do I pass the form class in each and every controller? I am having trouble creating the form because image.html.twig is included by the base.html.twig and base.html.twig is extended by all the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an independent controller for the form (the form being in its own independent `html.twig` alone), pass the form in that controller, and then render the controller inside `base.html.twig` like so

```
{{ render(controller('nameOfMyController:method')) }}
```

See [How to insert a Controller in Twig with "render" in Symfony 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221230/how-to-insert-a-controller-in-twig-with-render-in-symfony-2-2) for rendering controllers in Twig.