# call controller function with twig file with render is not working in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig

i try call controller function in twig file with render but it give error
this is my controller code
this is controller path

> \src\AppBundle\Controller\front\MenusController.php

MenusController.php Code

```
<?php

 namespace AppBundle\Controller\front;
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

 class MenusController extends Controller
 {

      public function menuAllAction()
      {
          return $this->render('front/menus.html.twig');
      }
 }
```

and this code is my twig file code
master.html.twig

```
{% render(controller('AppBundle:front:Menus:menuAll')) %}
```

but is return error please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a Controller in Twig with "render" in Symfony 2.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221230/how-to-insert-a-controller-in-twig-with-render-in-symfony-2-2)

Comment: Could you post the error message as well?

Comment: hey frd thnx for support but i found a solution                                             `render(controller('AppBundle:front\\Menus:menuAll'))`

Comment: Just for info, a single forward slash will work in place of two back slashes.

Answer (score 2):

Try like to replace `{%  %}` by `{{  }}`:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:front:Menus:menuAll')) }}
```

Edit:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Menus:menuAll')) }}
```

(the right synthax is: `bundle:controller:action`)

Comment: yes you are right but my controller in front folder look this path (\src\AppBundle\Controller\front\MenusController.php)